# what is wrong with this code to obtain some statistics after lapply() in R

Tags: r, list, statistics, regression, apply

My data is something like this:

```
ind1 <- rnorm(99)
ind2 <- rnorm(99)
ind3 <- rnorm(99)
ind4 <- rnorm(99)
ind5 <- rnorm(99)
dep <- rnorm(99, mean=ind1)
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=33)
df <- data.frame(dep,group, ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)
head(df)

         dep group        ind1       ind2       ind3       ind4          ind5
1 -3.4471651     A -1.61903503  0.8047651 -0.1498872 -0.1421423  0.0003106164
2  1.6097232     A -0.07202246 -1.7419735 -0.4600787 -0.8966089  0.5476866447
3  0.2419204     A  0.37266251  1.1456788  0.2693086 -0.7610068 -0.6588102710
4  0.4157412     A  1.17342107  0.4829935  1.5044331  0.4902491 -0.1845711119
5 -1.1026655     A  0.31428775  0.9488747  0.1806105  0.4187126 -0.4420550339
6  1.9605406     A  1.36719867  1.1116940  0.7026870  0.6450296 -1.0824261091
```

The next lines of code intend to run linear model for all possible combination of independent variables in the dataframe.

After selecting the significant models by p < 0.05 and ranking them by AIC value, I want to get following outputs: equation, estimate, R2, adj.R2, P value, AIC.

I tried it this way but the outputs are different from what I wanted. Does anyone have any idea to get them right?

```
 indvar_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) 
   combn(paste0("ind", 1:5), x, , simplify = FALSE))

 formulas_list <- rapply(indvar_list, function(x)
   as.formula(paste("dep ~", paste(x, collapse="+"))))

 mult.lm <- lapply(formulas_list, function(x) glance(lm(as.formula(x), 
 data = df)))

 outputs <- bind_rows(mult.lm, .id = 'index') %>%
   filter(p.value < 0.05) %>%
   arrange(AIC) %>%
   filter(index %in% head(unique(index)))
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show `df` as a reproudcible example for testing

Comment: Sorry it has been updated.

Comment: Different how? What did you get, and how is that different from what you wanted or expected?

Comment: if you're looking to rank models by forward/backward/exhaustive search by varying metrics you might want to take a look at the `leaps::regsubsets` package

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you're missing is the equation and estimate? The rest seems like it's exactly what you want. I think the issue is you're using "glance" which doesn't return these variables. I typically use `summary` when trying to get information from my model, but that doesn't include AIC. It's also not very clean to get at. You can add a second and third mult.lm which contain the estimates and our coefficient names used in the model, pasted together for simplicity.

```
mult.lm_est <- lapply(formulas_list, function(x) paste(summary(lm(as.formula(x), 
                                                       data = df))$coefficients[,1], collapse = ","))

mult.lm_coef <- lapply(formulas_list, function(x) paste(rownames(summary(lm(as.formula(x), 
                                                       data = df))$coefficients), collapse = ","))
```

Then you can bind rows on those lists as you did on your original, which will allow you to use dplyr joins by index

Comment: Thank you all! after obtaining the outputs can we use stargazer() to simple statistics that stargazer() provides?

Comment: @ A.Suliman. I applied this to my original data but I got this error "Error in data.frame(model = format(x), tidy(mod), glance(mod), stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 11, 1".  do you have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Use `base::format` to get the equation and `broom::tidy` to get the estimates "coefficients"

```
mult.lm <- lapply(formulas_list, function(x) {
mod <- lm(as.formula(x), data = df)
data.frame(model=format(x), tidy(mod), glance(mod), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
})

#To return more clean dataframe
mult.lm <- lapply(formulas_list, function(x) {
mod <- lm(as.formula(x), data = df)
tmod <- tidy(mod)
gmod <- glance(mod)
gmod[2:nrow(tmod),] <- ''

data.frame(model=c(format(x), rep('', nrow(tmod)-1)), tmod, gmod, 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
})
```